# Modules TS and pure virtual classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++20, c++-modules

## The Problem

I'm attempting to use a pure virtual class which I have defined in another module, however when attempting to use it I run into the following problem: `base class undefined`

### Bonus Info

In my search to determine what is the problem I have discovered that the namespace itself also suffers from a similar problem

### Compiler

I'm currently using the `VC++` compiler with the following additional settings:
`/std:c++latest /experimental:module /module:exportActiveMacros`which I did through the IDE project settings

### Code

As for the code it looks like the following:

#### Foo.ixx

```
module baa.foo;
export {
namespace BaaFoo {
    class InterfaceClassFoo {
    public:
        virtual void functionFoo() = 0;
    };
}
}
```

#### AnotherOne.ixx

```
import baa.foo;

module baa.foobar;
export {
namespace BaaFoo {
    class DerivedBaa : public InterfaceClassFoo { //Error Occurs Here
        virtual void functionFoo() { /*some magic */ }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? What are its build settings? And so forth.

Comment: Hiw does `AnotherOne` know where the pure virtual interface is declared?  Don't you need an import or somesuch?

Comment: @Yakk I merely forgot to add that on here, but yes I have imported the other module

Comment: Please post [mcve] -- make sure what you actually post generates the actual error.

Comment: This could be a compiler bug, since you are using an experimental feature.  Are you using the module and import features properly?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm To the best of my knowledge, I am using them correctly